# Infinite graph faithfully embedded in $\mathbb R^n$ has finitely many nodes in any bounded region?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(S,E)$ be a connected graph with a countably-infinite set of nodes $S$ and of bounded degree, $\Delta_G<\infty$. Let the Euclidean dimension $\mathrm{Edim}(G)$ of the graph be defined as by Erdős and Simonovits, the minimal dimension $n$ such that $G$ can be embedded in $\mathbb R^n$ such that all nodes connected by an edge are unit Euclidean distance apart and all nodes not connected by an edge are not unit distance apart (and called a *faithful embedding*). They showed in 1980 that $\mathrm{Edim}(G)\leq 2\Delta_G+1$.

Let us suppose $n\geq\mathrm{Edim}(G)$ and that we have such an embedding. Let's consider graph $G'$ to be this embedded graph in $\mathbb R^n$.

**Question:** Partition $\mathbb R^n$ into $n$-dimensional boxes with edge length $M$ in any arbitrary way. Am I guaranteed that each box only contains finitely many nodes?

Intuitively, it seems like the answer should be "yes." The simplest case is trying to embed the standard 1D integer lattice $\mathbb Z$ where only consecutive integers are connected by an edge. This is obviously already embedded in $\mathbb R^1$ and hence has the natural embedding in $\mathbb R^n$ for all $n$, and these embeddings are all "faithful." But can we pick $n$ so large that the integer axis can be twisted up in some way so as to fit all points in a finite box such that they are all distance one apart from neighbors but non-unit distance from non-neighbors? This seems intuitively impossible to me, but I'm just not sure.

Suppose we have such an embedding. Draw unit balls around each node. I can't imagine twisting up $\mathbb Z$ to fit inside a finite 2D rectangle, for example, but I cannot figure out how to prove this. Of course I also could be wrong too!

Maybe there is some "infinite star" which has "diameter 1" and infinitely many points, with points only unit distance apart when they are exactly on opposite sides of the star?

Or maybe bend up $\mathbb Z$ "like an accordion" where folds get increasingly tighter towards the ends so that, in the limit, it is all folded up into a finite rectangle. Of course, we'd have to choose the fold angles carefully enough so that only consecutive points are unit distance apart. Consider $\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ and map $0$ to the origin $(0,0)$, then map $1$ to $(\epsilon_1,\delta_1)$ for some $\epsilon_1,\delta_1\in(0,1)$ so that $\epsilon_1^2+\delta_1^2=1$, then map $2$ to $(\epsilon_2,0)$, and continue in this fashion with $2n$ mapping to $(\epsilon_{2n},0)$ and $2n-1$ mapping to $(\epsilon_{2n-1},\delta_{2n-1})$ for some sequence $\epsilon_n\to0$ fast enough to get $\sum_n \epsilon_n$ converges and $\delta_n\to1$. But we'd need to make sure points that are from consecutive integers are always unit distance apart and never unit distance apart for non-consecutive integers.

Comment: I don't think you need a large dimension for this. Consider embedding $\mathbb{N}$. First place $0$ anywhere. Then when placing $n+1$ the set of 'banned' points is the unit spheres around every point $x<n$. But these are all $d-1$ dimensional, so you'll always be able to find a point on the sphere around $n$ which is allowed, even if very little of the sphere is in the box. This works with $d=2$

Comment: @ZoeAllen ok, thanks for that succinct argument. So that at least confirms that a "faithful" embedding can fit infinitely many nodes in a finite box. I think I get your argument. There will always be uncountably-many points left as possibilities for $n+1$. That used an embedding into a higher dimensional space though. What if we embed the graph exactly in its $\mathsf{Edim}(G)$? Can a finite box there still contain infinitely many points? Clearly the example of $\mathbb N$ no longer works.

Comment: You can take three copies of $\mathbb N$ joined together at a common vertex $0$, which guarantees $\mathsf{Edim}(G) = 2$ since in $\mathbb R$ you can't have three vertices at distance $1$ from the same vertex. Then do the same thing.

Comment: @MishaLavrov If I understand, you are saying I can embed into $\mathbb R^2$ three copies of $\mathbb N$ (joined at 0, so like the $x,y,z$ integer axes) using the same trick above. Is there something special about 3 copies on $\mathbb N$ here? Now I almost feel like I could take any finite number of copies of $\mathbb Z$ (joined at origin) and embed into $\mathbb R^2$ using the same trick. Maybe even countably-many copies! I'd never run out of real $(x,y)$ coordinate pairs to choose form, no matter how many points I lay down. Does that sound even vaguely like I am on the right track?

Comment: That sounds right (though for countably many copies, the graph no longer has bounded degree). The special thing about $3$ is that we need *at least* $3$ copies of $\mathbb N$ in order to for the embedding dimension to be $2$ and not $1$ - larger numbers would also work.

Comment: @MishaLavrov yes, I didn't notice that the origin then has unbounded degree. Thank you so much for the insight!